# MatLab: is there a way to adjust fmincon to return a 3x4 matrix of parameters?

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics, nonlinear-optimization, estimation

I wrote the following code for MatLab but for now it clearly works only to return a row of parameters. The code is composed by the main file, the function file (MLE_GARCH) and the constraint file (nonlcon_GARCH) as follows:

```
clc
clear

%% Setup Data %%

% Input the price levels and dates.
Data = readtable('HSI.xlsx','Sheet','HSI Index');
Prices = Data.PX_LAST;
Dates = Data.Dates;

% Continuous risk free rate.
dt = 1/252;     % Daily time steps
rfd = [0.01 0.02 0.03]*dt;   % Duan risk-free rate
rfbs = rfd/dt;   %BS risk-free rate

% Define the returns (pad first return with risk-free rate).
r = [rfd; repmat(diff(log(Prices)),1,3)];
residuals = r - mean(r);
size = length(r);

%% Duan (1995) Pricing Model Estimation %%

% Starting values for constrained optimization.
start  = [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1];
A = [0 1 1 0];
b = 1;
lb = [eps 0 0 -Inf];  % Lower bound for parameters
ub = [Inf Inf Inf Inf];   % Upper bound for parameters
[params,fval,exitflag,output,llambda,grad,hessian] = fmincon(@(p) ...
    MLE_GARCH(p, Prices, rfd), start, A, b, [], [], lb, ub, @(c) Nonlcon_GARCH(c));

alpha0 = params(1);
alpha1 = params(2);
beta1  = params(3);
lambda = params(4);
```

This one above is the main file.

```
function y = MLE_GARCH(params,S,rf)

% Finds log-likelihood for the GARCH option pricing model.
alpha0 = params(1);
alpha1 = params(2);
beta1  = params(3);
lambda = params(4);

N = length(S);

% Define the returns (pad first return with risk-free rate)
r(1,:) = [rf; price2ret(S)];

% Infer the other conditional instantaneous variances
h(1)  = alpha0/(1 - alpha1 - beta1);

% Initialize the conditional variance recursion
for i=2:N
    h(i) = alpha0 + alpha1*(r(i-1) - rf - lambda*sqrt(h(i-1)) + ... 
        0.5*h(i-1))^2 + beta1*h(i-1);
end

% Initialize the log-likelihood recursion
for i=1:N
    LL(i) = - 0.5*log(h(i)) - 0.5/h(i)*(r(i) - rf - lambda*sqrt(h(i)) + ...
        0.5*h(i))^2;
end

% Return the negative log-likelihood function
y = -sum(LL);
```

This other one is the function file.

```
function [c, ceq] = Nonlcon_GARCH(params)

alpha0 = params(1);
alpha1 = params(2);
beta1  = params(3);
lambda = params(4);

% Set inequality constraints for parameters estimation.
c = alpha1*(1 + lambda^2) + beta1 - 1 - eps;
ceq = [];
```

And this last one is the constraint for fmincon.
I already tried to change some things in the main file and before the optimisation part everything is fine. However, when I started changing the function file, fmincon does not run and it tells me that "A must have 16 column(s)". The modified function file is as follows:

```
function y = MLE_GARCH_(params,S,rf)

% Finds log-likelihood for the GARCH option pricing model.
alpha0 = params(1,:);
alpha1 = params(2,:);
beta1  = params(3,:);
lambda = params(4,:);

N = length(S);

% Define the returns (pad first return with risk-free rate)
r = [rf; repmat(price2ret(S),1,3)];

% Infer the other conditional instantaneous variances
h(1,:)  = alpha0./(1 - alpha1 - beta1);

% Initialize the conditional variance recursion
for i=2:N
    h(i,:) = alpha0 + alpha1.*(r(i-1,:) - rf(:) - lambda.*sqrt(h(i-1,:)) + ... 
        0.5*h(i-1,:)).^2 + beta1.*h(i-1,:);
end

% Initialize the log-likelihood recursion
for i=1:N
    LL(i,:) = - 0.5.*log(h(i,:)) - 0.5./h(i,:).*(r(i,:) - rf(:) - lambda.*sqrt(h(i,:)) + ...
        0.5.*h(i,:))^2;
end

% Return the negative log-likelihood function
y = -sum(LL);
```

Given that my original code runs without problems, how can I change it to make it return a 3x4 matrix of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite long question with a lot of code that we cannot replicate because it uses a xls-file on your HDD. You may want to post a minimum viable example (MVE) for us?

Anyway, the short answer is: **no**.
The long anser is: Why should someone do this? Change your cost function that is builds the 3x4 matrix from a 12x1 vector and your are done.